# Push multi container image ecr/ecs

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-ecs, bitbucket-pipelines, amazon-ecr

I have a docker-compose file which I want to deploy on production.
I am considering using `bitbucket-pipelines` along with `ECR/ECS`.
How can I push the multi-container docker-compose to ECS ?
I am also looking forward to suggestions/ideas to make this process seamless.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  service1:
    container_name: service1
    build: 
      context: https://my-git-repo.git
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    expose:
      - 3001
    ports:
      - 3001:3001
    restart: on-failure
  service2:
    container_name: service1
    build: 
      context: https://my-service1-git-repo.git
    env_file:
      - .env
    networks:
      - my-app-network
    expose:
      - 3002
    ports:
      - 3002:3002
    restart: on-failure
volumes:
  my-data:
    external: false
networks:
  my-app-network:
    external: false
    driver: bridge
```

**Bitbucket-pipelines.yml**

```
image: atlassian/default-image:3

pipelines:
  branches:
    develop:
      - step:
          name: Build Image
          image: python:3.8.1
          services:
            - docker
          caches:
            - docker
            - pip
          script:
            - pip install docker-compose
            - docker-compose version
            - docker image prune
            - docker-compose -f docker-compose.yml -f docker-compose.prod.yml --env-file .env.dev build
            # - docker-compose down
      - step:
          name: Push Image to Registry
          image: atlassian/pipelines-awscli
          caches:
            - docker
          services:
            - docker
          script:
            - pipe: atlassian/aws-ecr-push-image:2.0.0
              variables:
                AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID: $AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID
                AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY: $AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
                AWS_DEFAULT_REGION: ap-north-1
                APPLICATION_NAME: app-name  
                IMAGE_NAME: image-test
      - step:
          name: Deploy to Production
          deployment: Production
          script:
            - echo Deploy to Production
```

**How I want the process to be seamless?**

When I push the code to a `service repo` a bitbucket pipeline is triggered in a separate `deployment repo` which contains all the deployment scripts related to all the services, (service repo(code push) -> bitbucket-pipeline -> deployement repo -> bitbucket-pipeline -> ECR -> ECS).

**What have I tried?**

Tried pushing all docker images built in with docker-compose to ECR but have failed.

**What challenges?**

Pushing single image to ECR is easy, challenge is when you have 10 service repos and you want to push the updated/all docker images to ECR/ECS.

**What have I achieved?**

- Triggering bitbucket pipeline from `service repo` to `deployment repo`
- Creating docker images using bitbucket pipelines

Comment: I'm not sure if you'll use this docker-compose to deploy to ECS. But I know that bitbucket pipelines have a script that handles ecs deployment. You'll have to setup the task definition for your ECS service in a JSON format (where you can setup as many containers as you want) and pass it as parameter in the BBP script. Checkout this article: https://dev.to/olaoluwa98/easy-deployment-setup-with-bitbucket-and-aws-ecs-46ac